# Fade in animation image in Android giving black screen

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image

I want my picture to fade in (I think this is how you call it...). I am currently trying to use the alpha to do this (see below). But the alpha is getting a black screen and then showing the picture. I need the animation to show the picture in the beginning but a transparent  one or very bright picture and then get darker and fill the color as the animation progresses.

Hope I explained myself correctly...

```
 AlphaAnimation fadein = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
     //fadein.setFillAfter(true);
     fadein.setDuration(1000);
     apa.startAnimation(fadein);
     animationmove=3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to partially visible to start with, you can do one of the two following options:

1. Create a low opacity image and set it as the background of the parent layout.
2. Change the initial alpha to a small, non-zero value:

   AlphaAnimation fadein = new AlphaAnimation(0.2, 1);

After animation, The image you animate will probably return to its original state.

There are three "setFill..." methods you can use.
`fadein.setFillBefore(true)` makes it start in the finished animation state, provided that you declare `fadein.setFillEnabled(true)`.

`fadein.setFillAfter(true)` makes the animated image retain its final state after animation.

You can also declare these in the animation.xml files between the , .

Comment: Thanks! set it to  AlphaAnimation fadein = new AlphaAnimation(0.2, 1); and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

create anim/alpha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000">
```

and in java file

```
Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,anim.alpha);
    iv.startAnimation(an);
```